# Loop through Filtered List and highlight 20 percent of total visible rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list which was auto filtered.

My goal is to highlight the 20 percent of the total visible row.

I have a code already, however, I am not sure on how to proceed to highlight the 20 percent starting from the first visible row.

The code below highlights all visible rows:

```
Sub HighlightTwentyPercent()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Set sht = Worksheets("Input raw")
Set StartCell = Range("F2")
Dim cl As Range


LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set rng = sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, 6))

For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    cl.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 12, 29)

Next cl

End Sub
```

Example:

If the total visible row is 50, then it will highlight 20 percent. In this case, it will highlight 10 rows from the first visible row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will calculate the number of rows that equate to 20% of the visible rows and then it will Exit the For Loop once that number has been reached:

```
Sub HighlightTwentyPercent()

Dim sht As Worksheet: Set sht = Worksheets("Input raw")
Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range, rng As Range
Dim cl As Range
Dim TwentyPc As Long, i As Long
Set StartCell = Range("F2")

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set rng = sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, 6))
TwentyPc = Round(rng.Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count * 0.2, 0)

For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    i = i + 1
    If i > TwentyPc Then Exit For
    cl.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 12, 29)
Next cl
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Xabier! I tested the code and achieve what I needed to do. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without VBA, using the following conditional format rule (assuming your data is on `F2:F51` per your example):

```
=SUBTOTAL(3,$F$2:$F2)<=SUBTOTAL(3,$F$2:$F$51)/5
```

You may need to tweak it depending on how you want to handle rounded values (e.g. if you want to highlight 2 visible rows out of 9).

Comment: You've beaten me to it. I would have recommended using something like `=ROW(F1)<=SUBTOTAL(3,$F:$F)/5` on visible cells only. +1 :)

Comment: That was my first attempt, but `ROW()` doesn't care whether the row is visible or not.